# On Db2 v11.1, how do we get or setup the notification for DBA team if there is any hang or slowness situation in offshift working hours?

Tags: db2, database-administration, db2-luw

On Db2 v11.1, how do we get or setup the notification for DBA team if there is any hang or slowness situation in off shift working hours?

Comment: Appreciate any feedback here.

Comment: I don't see any automated way of doing it from Db2 side.
So would be interested to know what others do for such notifications.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the  external monitoring and alerting solution you deployed, and how you configure that tooling in your environment.

This application layer tooling is **not** built into Db2-LUW, although APIs exist in Db2-LUW for such tooling to get the data it needs in order to operate.

IBM and several third parties offer solutions for real time monitoring and alerting in this space. Many cover app-servers, web-servers, database layers, networks and operating-system layers and have different alerting configurability.  Many have plugin type architecture with plugins for Db2-LUW monitoring.  Do not use stackoverflow for product recommendations however.

For "slowness", this is only meaningful to measure usually at the **application** layer, in terms of response times and other metrics etc.

For database-hangs, IBM offers a `db2-hang_detect` script that tooling can orchestrate , requires careful interpretation and even more careful testing.